# Maximum of the minimum of two functions

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have two functions, each with 15 variables.  How can I find maximum (minimum) of these functions?  I know that minimum (maximum) of two functions is a multi-criteria function but I cannot find it.  For example, assume two function are these:

$f(x,y,z)=x+2y-5z$

$g(x,y,z)=4x-y+9z$

Comment: May look up `FindMaxValue` and `FindMinValue` in the documentation.

Comment: no, those functions find maximum(minimum) of a function.

Comment: What do you mean by "...maximum... is a multi-criteria function"?

Comment: i say that minimum of two functions, is a function too,such that  multi-criteria function and so on... but it  is not a number.

Comment: I simply do not understand what you mean by "multi-criteria function."  Can you give an example of a *non multi-criteria function* and an example of a *multi-criteria function*?  Do you mean, for example, *MinMax*?

Comment: With your given functions f and g, what do you expect the answer to look like?

Answer (score 5):

One common approach for "maxmin" problems, i.e., of the form

> maximimize (over $\{x_i\}$) $\min \{f_i(x_i)\}$,

is to introduce an additional variable, say $t$, and reformulate the problem as

> maximize (over $t$ and $\{x_i\}$) $t$, subject to $f_i(x_i)\geq t, \forall i$.

Example:

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x + 2 y - 5 z;
g[x_, y_, z_] := 4 x - y + 9 z;
FindMaximum[{t, 
  f[x, y, z] >= t && g[x, y, z] >= t && 0 <= x <= 0.1 && 
   0 <= y <= 10 && 0 <= z <= 1}, {{t, 0}, {x, 0}, {y, 0}, {z, 0}}]
```

> {4.63333, {t -> 4.63333, x -> 0.1, y -> 4.76667, z -> 1.}}

P.S.: I imposed additional (arbitrary) constraints on the range of values of $x,y,z$ to make the objective function bounded.